# Binding Rich Text to Textarea using ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I have a textarea in which I want to store some text having rich format 
For this I want to use ckeditor.

Jquery i am using is

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea#editorX').ckeditor();
    });
</script>
```

I am facing several issues with ckedito:

1. Unable to remove the toolbar of ckeditor
2. Cannot resize the ckeditor
3. Ckeditor is displayed but I cannot type or paste in it.
4. data entered in ckeditor not binding to text area.

I have tried various links and stuff , but unable to understand, also I would like to know if there is **any other best method to keep and store rich text format in textarea ??**.

Please Help !!

Comment: you should look at the ckeditor config file. post what kind of config you are currently using, that would enable you to get help faster.

Comment: CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.height = 400;
    //config.toolbar = [['NewPage']];
    config.startupFocus = true;
    config.startupMode = 'source';
};

This is my config file